# One (mandatory) to many (mandatory) relationship in SQL

Tags: sql, database, entity-relationship, relationship

I am new in SQL and I would like to develop a database where i will have two tables(employee, shop) with One-to-many relationship from parent entity set "shop" to child entity set "employee". How can I create a constraint in SQL (javaDB, Apache Derby) to check that each shop must have at least one or more employees and each employee must work to at most one shop. This is just an example but I am interested mainly in the mandatory participation at one side in one-to-many relationship.I know how to create constraint on the child entity set (many side) about the parent entity but i would like to know how to create constraint on parent entity set (one side) about the child entity set.

Any help would really help. Regards

Comment: Well that would require that on insertion of a new shop, an employee is allocated to it, and that employee would have to belong to a shop before it can be created so it would be a circular reference.

Comment: I'm assuming you'll have a shop_id in the shop table and a shop_id in the employee table. What do you want to happen if someone tries to add a shop that does not have at least one employee with a corresponding shop_id? Also, in this case, other than using a deferred constraint such that you could add a new shop and then subsequently add a new employee in the same transaction.

Comment: You really can't.  When adding a enw employee they may not be assigned to a shop, or when setting up a shop, they may not be linked to an employee.  You can't enforce this as the database has to do the inserts in order.  Shop then employee or employee then shop.  Either way, one has to be first which violates the rule of the other.  It has to be optional at least one way, or the data should reside in the same table, then you could check that at least both fields are populated. but you said you have two tables...  you can write a report/query to list shops w/o employee or vise versa though.

Comment: Depending on how you do it. You could use triggers to do some logic and throw exceptions.

Comment: Another way to enforce this in SQL is with an `ASSERTION` which is like a constraint that applies to more than one table. Unfortunately, even though assertions are defined in the SQL standard, I don't know of any current RDBMS that implements this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a database that supports deferrable foreign keys (like Postgresql), then you could do it. You'd need a trigger on your parent table insert.

Not sure about using autogenerated keys.

```
create table parent (
  id int primary key
);

create function has_kids() returns trigger as $$
begin

  if not exists (select 1 from child where parent_id = new.id) then
    raise exception 'insert a child first';
  end if;

  return new;

end $$ language plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER has_kids BEFORE INSERT ON parent
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE has_kids();

create table child (
  id int primary key,
  parent_id int not null references parent(id) initially deferred deferrable
);



begin transaction;
insert into child (id, parent_id) values (1, 1);
insert into parent (id) values (1);
commit;
```

Comment: OP mentions Apache Derby, which does not support deferrable constraints. I found the following feature request open since 2005, with a current state of "in progress" as of today. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-532

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan, Thank you a lot for that help but can i have the equivalent syntax in SQL that i can use in mySQL? thanks

Comment: I'm afraid that I cannot condone the use of mysql over postgres.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much coding you want to do to add new records to both tables later on, this may not be a viable option. I've seen designs where there is a scheduled job that checks the Shop table and moves any shops that don't have any employees assigned to it to another table such as "Empty_Shops". Then, when adding a new employee, you would scan Shops for the employee's shop_id and if it doesn't exist, scan the Empty_Shops table for that shop_id and move the missing shop_id back into Shops before adding the new employee.

That said, I don't know how to accomplish what you're asking about using solely constraints without running into a circular reference as @Kell mentioned.

Comment: Thank you but i would like to have a direct way to resolve that. Regards.